# jQuery: Easy way to quick select a whole optgroup in select box

Tags: jquery, html, optgroup

I use a jQuery function similar to the one in this thread: 
[Easy way to quick select a whole optgroup in select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473897/easy-way-to-quick-select-a-whole-optgroup-in-select-box)

But, when I click an `<option>` now it selects the whole optgroup, as the optgroup encloses the option elements.
I use the following snippet:

```
  $("optgroup").click(function(e) {
    $(this).children().attr('selected','selected');
  });
```

my HTML looks like this:

```
<optgroup label="Abc">
<option value="8" >Ab</option> 
<option value="7" >C</option></optgroup>
```

So clickig on `<option>C</option>` selects `<option>Ab</option>` as well. Perhaps I am missing something obvious...

Comment: Which browser are you checking this in?  Some browsers won't fire the `click` event (IE for starters), so you may want to re-visit your whole approach here.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your question. 
I am testing in Chrome/Safari/Firefox for now. It wouldn't be that bad if IE does not fire the click, it's just a convenience option. But it gets inconvenient if users can't select single options.

Comment: Ah alright, sounds good in that case, was just making sure you were aware...I've seen click on `<option>` here result it "victory, it works!.....ah crap IE" too many times :)

Comment: ;-) hehe, Olis approach solved it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong but you might need to add a handler to the `<option>`s to stop the click event bubbling up.

Something as simple as this *might* help:

```
$("optgroup option").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

also, you could check the target in your optgroup click handler, and short-circut if the event's target is actually an option tag, like so:

```
$("optgroup").click(function(e) {
   if ($(e.target).is('option')) return;
   $(this).children().attr('selected','selected');
});
```