# Jquery - Be able to select items in drop down by group?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down that has the group label:

```
<optgroup label="Numbers">

    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>

</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Letters" disabled="true">

    <option value="4">A</option>
    <option value="5">B</option>
    <option value="6">C</option>

</optgroup>
```

Is there a jquery plugin that exist that will allow me to click the group label and that will auto select all the options in that group? Or if not does anyone know how this can be done in jquery, if it can be done at all? Basically I want to click the optgroup label as an option, when I do that all options assigned to that group will be selected/checked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473897/easy-way-to-quick-select-a-whole-optgroup-in-select-box

Comment: @MikeG Can you move that to an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of css classes and the jquery children() method should do the trick. This answer gives a good example: [Easy way to quick select a whole optgroup in select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473897/easy-way-to-quick-select-a-whole-optgroup-in-select-box)